# Prove that $\cap_{i \in I} A_i = \cap_{X \in \mathcal{F}} ( \cap_{i \in X} A_i)$ where $I = \cup \mathcal{F}$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a nonempty family of sets. Let $I = \cup \mathcal{F}$ and $J = \cap \mathcal{F}$.
>   Suppose also that $J \neq \varnothing$, and notice that it follows that for every $X \in \mathcal{F}$,
>   $X \neq \varnothing$, and also that $I \neq \varnothing$. Finally, suppose that $\{A_i | i ∈ I \}$ is an
>   indexed family of sets.
>
> Prove that $\cap_{i \in I} A_i = \cap_{X \in \mathcal{F}} ( \cap_{i \in X} A_i)$.

I attempted to prove it using equivalences. When I was figuring out the equivalences I made sure that the statements were equivalent but did not include this in the final proof, but I am not sure whether I am allowed to do this.

My attempt:

$x \in \cap_{i \in I} A_i$

iff $\forall i \in I(x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall i \in \cup \mathcal{F} (x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall i ( \exists X(X \in \mathcal{F} \land i \in X) \rightarrow x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall i ( \lnot \exists X(X \in \mathcal{F} \land i \in X) \lor x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall i ( \forall X \lnot (X \in \mathcal{F} \land i \in X) \lor x \in A_i)$

iff $ \forall X \forall i ( \lnot (X \in \mathcal{F} \land i \in X) \lor x \in A_i)$

iff $ \forall X \forall i ( (X \in \mathcal{F} \land i \in X) \rightarrow x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall X \in \mathcal{F} \forall i \in X (x \in A_i)$

iff $\forall X \in \mathcal{F} (x \in \cap_{i \in X} A_i)$

iff $x \in \cap_{X \in \mathcal{F}} (\cap_{i \in X} A_i)$

Therefore, $\cap_{i \in I} A_i = \cap_{X \in \mathcal{F}} ( \cap_{i \in X} A_i)$.